# perl: Cannot capture the eval return value

Tags: perl

I get a strange issue for perl eval return value. I want to store some hash data structure in txt file and then restore it by eval.
The following code works in my test.pl

```
  use Data::Dumper;
  my $read_str = `cat sims/pgcache/.gsim/metadata.txt`;
  my $metadata = eval($read_str);
  print STDERR "read_str = $read_str\n";
  print Dumper("metadata",$metadata);
  print 'perl version = ',$^V,"\n";
```

But when I inject this code to our existed large perl script, the $metadata returns nothing with the $read_str is exactly the same as my test.pl.

I have already checked the perl version and they are just the same. Any clue about this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using `strict`? `Data::Dumper` output begins with `$VAR1 = ...`. If you haven't declared a variable called `$VAR1`, `strict` will make your program fail.

```
my $read_str = `cat sims/pgcache/.gsim/metadata.txt`;
my $VAR1;
my $metadata = eval($read_str);
```

"Gosh", you say. "What an esoteric piece of knowledge. How would I ever be expected to know that and to solve this problem?"

Well, when `eval` fails (and one generally uses `eval` in cases where it can be expected to fail some of the time), the error message will be written to `$@` (that is a less esoteric piece of knowledge, available in the [`eval`](http://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#eval) or [perlvar](http://metacpan.org/pod/perlvar) docs). So when you use `eval`, and especially when `eval` doesn't seem to return anything, you should check `$@`.

```
use strict;
my $read_str = '$VAR1 = {}';
my $metadata = eval($read_str);
die $@ if $@;
```

produces: `Global symbol "$VAR1" requires explicit package name at (eval 1) line 1.`

Comment: Oh, man! Thank you very much! It's exactly the use strict issue. Our large perl script put the use strict in some files instead the file where my code was injected.

Answer (score 6):

Don't do this. `Data::Dumper` is intended as a debugging tool

A better way is to use *Makamaka's* [`JSON`](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON) module to *serialise* your data structure, using the `to_json` and `from_json` functions

You should also avoid starting a whole new process just to use `cat` to read a text file. Perl is quite able to read files without any help

Here's an example. Just like your own code, it shows only the decoding process, and requires a file `sims/pgcache/.gsim/metadata.txt` which contains a JSON data structure before it will work

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use JSON;
use Data::Dumper;

my $json_str = do {
    open my $fh, '<', 'sims/pgcache/.gsim/metadata.txt' or die $!;
    local $/;
    <$fh>;
};

my $metadata = from_json $json_str;

print STDERR "json_str = $json_str\n";

print Dumper( "metadata", $metadata );
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I thought cat is more efficient than perl open. Do you mean the open function is the faster one?

Comment: cat is doing the same thing _and_ opening another redundant process.

Comment: @XinweiGong: It is generally much better to keep everything inside Perl wherever possible. `open`/`readline` is *hugely* faster than starting a new process just to run `cat`.

Comment: Thanks you guys so much for useful info. My script has high performance requirement.

Comment: @Borodin I have two more quesiton for your example code: 1. why you use 'do' for open file and not call the close sentence? 2. Does JSON::from_json  have better performance than eval? I used Data::Dumper because it can be restored by eval() and it doesn't need any string parser which I thought it had better performance.

Comment: @Borodin I google the $/ and get the answer for question 1. But in my usage, I will have thousands parallel LSF jobs to access the same file for read and each one only get different several lines. So read the entire file which > 100MB could not be efficient. Currently, I use my $db_str = `awk 'FNR>=$start_line && FNR<=$end_line' $listfile`;  to make it better performance. But it did opening another process.

Comment: @XinweiGong: You can't split up a serialised data structure, whether it's encoded using `JSON` or `Data::Dumper`. You should use`JSON::XS` for speed.

Comment: @Borodin I create two scripts, one with JSON and the other with Data::Dumper+eval. Both of them run 1000 rounds and the work is just generate a hash, store it to file by to_json or Dumper, then reload by eval or to_json. It seems the eval script run x20+ faster than json version with even less memory. My data structure is an array whose element is a fixed size hash and that's why I can split up it by select specified lines from file.

Comment: @XinweiGong:  Use `JSON::XS` as I said. The interface is the same, so you can just change the `use` statement once it's installed.

Comment: @XinweiGong:  Have you considered [Storable](https://metacpan.org/pod/Storable)? It writes a binary file without converting the data to text, and if you use `store_fd` and `fd_retrieve` then you can store multiple data structures in a file and read them sequentially, one at a time.